# Change a property's value in one component from within another component

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vue-component

I'm trying to wrap my head around hoe Vue.js works, reading lots of documents and tutorials and taking some pluralsight classes.  I have a very basic website UI up and running. Here's the App.vue (which I'm using kinda as a master page).

*(To make reading this easier and faster, look for this comment:  `This is the part you should pay attention to`)...*

```
<template>
    <div id="app">
        <div>
            <div>
                <CommandBar />
            </div>
            <div>
                <Navigation />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="lowerContent">

            <!-- This is the part you should pay attention to -->

            <template v-if="showLeftContent">
                <div id="leftPane">
                    <div id="leftContent">
                        <router-view name="LeftSideBar"></router-view>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </template>

            <!-- // This is the part you should pay attention to -->

            <div id="mainPane">
                <div id="mainContent">
                    <router-view name="MainContent"></router-view>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

And then in the same App.vue file, here's the script portion

```
<script lang="ts">
    import { Component, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';

    import CommandBar from './components/CommandBar.vue';
    import Navigation from './components/Navigation.vue';


    @Component({
        components: {
            CommandBar,
            Navigation,
        }
    })
    export default class App extends Vue {
        data() {
            return {
                showLeftContent: true // <--- This is the part you should pay attention to
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Ok, so the idea is, one some pages I want to show a left sidebar, but on other pages I don't.  That's why that div is wrapped in `<template v-if="showLeftContent">`.

Then with the named `<router-view>'s` I can control which components get loaded into them in the `router\index.ts\ file. The routes look like this:

```
    {
        path: '/home',
        name: 'Home',
        components: {
            default: Home,
            MainContent: Home,  // load the Home compliment the main content
            LeftSideBar: UserSearch  // load the UserSearch component in the left side bar area
        }
    },
```

So far so good!  But here's the kicker.  Some pages won't have a left side bar, and on those pages, I want to change `showLeftContent` from `true` to `false`.  That's the part I can't figure out.

Let's say we have a "Notes" component that looks like this.

```
<template>
    <div class="notes">
        Notes
    </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
    import { Component, Prop, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';

    @Component
    export default class Notes extends Vue {
        data() {
            return {
                showLeftContent: false  // DOES NOT WORK
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Obviously, I'm not handling `showLeftContent` properly here. It would seem as if the properties in `data` are scoped only to that component, which I understand.  I'm just not finding anything on how I can set a data property in the App component and then change it in a child component when that child is loaded through a `router-view`.

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

I changed the script section of the Notes component from:

```
<script lang="ts">
    import { Component, Prop, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';

    @Component
    export default class Notes extends Vue {
        data() {
            return {
                showLeftContent: false  // DOES NOT WORK
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

to:

```
<script lang="ts">
    import { Component, Prop, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';

    @Component
    export default class Notes extends Vue {
        mounted() {
            this.$root.$data.showLeftContent = false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

And while that didn't cause any compile or runtime errors, it also didn't have the desired effect.  On `Notes`, the left side bar still shows.

**EDIT 2:**

If I put an alert in the script section of the Notes component:

```
export default class Notes extends Vue {
    mounted() {
        alert(this.$root.$data.showLeftContent);
        //this.$root.$data.showLeftContent = false;
    }
}
```

The alert does not pop until I click on "Notes" in the navigation.  But, the value is "undefined".

**EDIT 3:**

Struggling with the syntax here (keep in mind this is TypeScript, which I don't know very well!!)

[image]

**Edit 4:**

Inching along!

```
export default class App extends Vue {
    data() {
        return {
            showLeftContent: true
        }
    }

    leftContent(value: boolean) {
        alert('clicked');
        this.$root.$emit('left-content', value);
    }
}
```

This does not result in any errors, but it also doesn't work.  The event never gets fired.  I'm going to try putting it in the Navigation component and see if that works.

Comment: Are you sure **Notes** component already mounted? Probably add one `console.log` to double check it.

Comment: @Sphinx, see edit 2

Comment: if the value is 'undefined', probably caused by **App** is not the root instance. double check by `console.log(this.$root.$el)`.

Comment: lol, I don't know typescript either (for edit 3). added **typescript** tag.

Comment: `this.$root.$emit('left-content', value);` should be called at the Component which want to hide/show side panel. and you didn't define `this.$on`

Comment: Yeah that makes sense, but I can't get that to trigger from within the Navigation component

Answer (score 4):

As it says on @lukebearden answer you can use the emit event to pass true/false to the main `App` component on `router-link` click.

Assuming your `Navigation` component looks like below, you can do something like that:

```
#Navigation.vue
<template>
  <div>
      <router-link to="/home" @click.native="leftContent(true)">Home</router-link> - 
      <router-link to="/notes" @click.native="leftContent(false)">Notes</router-link>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    leftContent(value) {
      this.$emit('left-content', value)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

And in your main `App` you listen the emit on `Navigation`:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div>
      <Navigation @left-content="leftContent" />
    </div>
    <div id="lowerContent">
      <template v-if="showLeftContent">
         //...
      </template>

      <div id="mainPane">
         //...
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  //...
  data() {
    return {
      showLeftContent: true
    }
  },
  methods: {
    leftContent(value) {
      this.showLeftContent = value
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: @CaseyCrookston i don't know ts very well but i think you don't need this block `methods: { ... }` to initialize a method.

Comment: @CaseyCrookston about your edit 4, it's not `App` which emits the `'left-content'` event, it's `Navigation` (and you don't need the`$root`). `App` listen the event on the navigation component.

Comment: @sovalina, can you show me how that would look? Man, I solve one problem and another one crops up!!  I REALLY appreciate your help!!

Comment: @CaseyCrookston i made a [codesandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/embed/1w4jpn6l3) to test the router-link (but it's not in typescript)

Comment: Oh man I am starting to really second guess my decision to use TypeScript!  Thank you for this!!

Comment: Yeah, trying to learn TypeScript and Vue at once is probably working against you.

Comment: @CaseyCrookston If `/notes` is a route, you could alternatively exclude `LeftSideBar` from its route components: https://codesandbox.io/s/6lp16pwjpr

Comment: Good solution (adjust route setting). I fell into one trap, always thinking about how to control leftSidePanel by the component view itself, whatever how deeper is.

Answer (score 2):

A basic approach in a parent-child component relationship is to emit events from the child and then listen and handle that event in the parent component.

However, I'm not sure that approach works when working with the router-view. This person solved it by watching the $route attribute for changes. https://forum.vuejs.org/t/emitting-events-from-vue-router/10136/6

You might also want to look into creating a simple event bus using a vue instance, or using vuex.

Comment: or `this.$root.$emit/$on` will be one option.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to access the data property (or props, options etc) of **the root instance**, you can use `this.$root.$data`. (Check [Vue Guide: Handling Edge](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Accessing-the-Root-Instance))

**For your codes**, you can change `this.$root.$data.showLeftContent` to true/false in the hook=`mounted` of other Components, then when Vue creates instances for those components, it will show/hide the left side panel relevantly.

**Below is one demo**:

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.component('child', {
  template: `<div :style="{'background-color':color}" style="padding: 10px">
                Reach to root: <button @click="changeRootData()">Click me!</button>
                <hr>
                <slot></slot>
             </div>`,
  props: ['color'],
  methods: {
    changeRootData() {
      this.$root.$data.testValue += ' :) '
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      testValue: 'Puss In Boots'
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h2>{{testValue}}</h2>
  <child color="red"><child color="gray"><child color="green"></child></child></child>

</div>
```

Comment: in the root App component, should I be using a prop instead of data?  Meaning, should showLeftContent be a prop instead of part of the data() object?

Comment: @CaseyCrookston, Vue works under one way data flow. one component shouldn't change the value of its props. So I don't think it is a good idea to use one prop instead of the data property.

Comment: ok, thanks.  That makes sense.  So... I'm still struggling to know how to change the data property 'showLeftContent'

Comment: If do an alert, like this: alert(this.$root.$data.showLeftContent);
it comes back "undefined"